# Using the same template for listing subcategories and posts

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to use the same template (category-slug.php) to do the following:

Check if category has children - we show subcategories

otherwise - we display all posts that belong to a specific category

So what's the correct way to do so?  How many templates I need for this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in the same template file like so:

```
<?php
    // list child categories
    $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');

    $catlist = wp_list_categories('echo=0&orderby=id&title_li=&child_of=' . $cat_id);

 if (get_categories('parent=' . $cat_id)) {
     echo $catlist;
     } else {
      // normal loop
     }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, appreciate your reply!!